# Cannot select provisioning profile in Appcelerator Studio for In-House Distribution

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, provisioning-profile, appcelerator-studio

I think the title already describes my issue. I try to deploy an iOS App as an In-House application using Appcelerator Studio 4.9. I currently have Xcode 8.3.3 installed. I just upgraded from an older Version of Appcelerator Studio and cannot select the Provisioning Profile for my application in the Deploy Dialog.
But I can select the correct Distribution Certificate though.

Here is what I checked:
I have my Distribution Certificate installed, have the correct provisioning profile installed (which is not expired yet) and even can see the Profil in the Setting.
The profile is a distribution profile for In-House, and got the correct bundle ID matching the App once. Also I tried a couple of things like login in and out (on Studio as well as the CLI), generating a new profile and installing it, restarting computer, etc..

Any ideas what the issue might be or other tipps that I missed so far?

Comment: You followed the instructions to install the provisioning profile found at: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps-section-src-27595277_DistributingiOSapps-Createandinstallthedistributionprovisioningprofile ?  When you say you can see the profile in the settings, what do you mean? Can you screenshot it? You've selected iOS Ad Hoc / Enterprise as your target drop down selection?

Comment: @wottle thanks for you reply here! I just followed these instructions and that didn't help me either.
When I mean I can see it in the settings, is when I do a right-click on the project and click on Publish -> Ad Hoc / Enterprise I can NOT select it. But when I click on "Manage Settings" in this dialog I see it listed in the Provisioning Profile section. The weird thing is, that this also occures with an older (not expired) profile and I defnitly could deploy the app with that profile with an older Version of Appcelerator Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To package for “iOS Adhoc/Enterprise, you must have either ad-hoc or enterprise profile.  Distribution profiles are not shown on the “ iOS Adhoc/Enterprise” build. Distribution profiles are shown on “iOS iTunes store” packaging builds.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8729

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
Actually I have an `In-House and Ad-Hoc` profile and the profile it self shouldn't be the issue. I cannot get this running with an profile that I used before with an older version and therefore I could select it, neither can I use a new profile I just created.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a bug in Appcelerator Studio which was fixed in 4.9.1.